# How many electrons are in the $k$-space?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

Let's assume we have a metal cube with edge length $L$ and in its volume $L^3$ are $N$ conduction electrons. The components of the wave vector are quantized. i.e. $k_x=m\cdot (2\pi/L)$ where $m=0,\pm 1,\pm 2,\dots $.

Question: How many electrons can (at most) be in a volume element of the $k$-space $\triangle k_x \cdot\triangle k_y\cdot \triangle k_z=(2\pi/L)^3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the electrons are free, the single particle excitation spectrum is the well-known:
$$E_{k} = \frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m} (1)$$
where $\vec{k}$ is referred to the unique value of the wave-vector that exists in a unit cell.
By the Pauli exclusion principle, you know that you can have just one electron in a given quantum state, that, in this case, is labelled by the wave vector and the spin of the electron:
$$|\vec{k},S_{z} \rangle$$
where $S_{z}$ is the projection of the spin along the $z$ direction.
This means that you can have two  electrons in a single unit cell labeled with a wave-vector $\vec{k}$, beacuase of the spin degeneracy that in this case is:
$$(2S +1) = 2$$
where $S$ is the modulus of the spin that for an electron is $S=\frac{1}{2}$. Let's summarize: for a given wave vector $\vec{k}$, and so, for a fixed cell of the Fourier space, you can have two electrons with the same energy (1), described by the quantum states:
$$ |\vec{k},S_{z} \rangle = |\vec{k},\frac{1}{2} \rangle$$
$$ |\vec{k},S_{z} \rangle = |\vec{k},-\frac{1}{2} \rangle$$
This means that the answer to your question is: you can have at maximum 2 electrons per unit-cell and so you can have: two, one, or zero electrons.

Comment: Okay, so the other informations given in this problem are enitrely irrelevant for what's asked?

Comment: i don’t understand, what other informations?

Comment: The electron density in the "real" space $n=N/L^3$ for example.

Comment: No, it doesn't matter how much large is $n$. The general result is the one that i have written above.